# Php Page Language translation

Tags: php, translation

i am developing a php application which run on offline mode mean not connect with internet,

i want to convert my page language in different languages to facilitate user,

is there any way to do it without using online api's??

kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The short answer is most likely no - I know of no offline product comparable to Google Translate's API. At least no affordable one.

Comment: so what you suggest what i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually convert all strings by using [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) and then create the language files to be used by your offline PHP scripts.

Comment: there is no dll or api which we can use in offline mode to convert page in selected language?

Comment: @Emaad, There is none that I know of and there are 99.99% chance that there is no such API.

Comment: is there any way to use wamp server dll for converting php pages?

Answer (score 0):

There is unlikely to be a piece of free software that will come anywhere *near* what Google Translate has to offer.

You will need to define what languages you need, and look/ask for translation programs for those languages. Be prepared to be spending some serious money on this, though: I don't know of any free programs that can really *translate* text.

Either that, or get an Internet connection for that server after all, and use Google Translate. It's probably the cheapest way.